# Group 2d array by date portion of datetime column and sum another column

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, sum, grouping

I have a 2d array with a datetime column and a subtotal column.  I need to group the rows by the date portion of their datetime value and sum the subtotal values in each group.

Sample input array:

```
[
    ['id' => 81, 'placed' => '2013-09-19 16:32:53', 'sub_total' => 786],
    ['id' => 80, 'placed' => '2013-09-19 16:32:06', 'sub_total' => 780],
    ['id' => 79, 'placed' => '2013-09-18 17:06:48', 'sub_total' => 786],
    ['id' => 78, 'placed' => '2013-09-18 17:05:02', 'sub_total' => 756],
    ['id' => 77, 'placed' => '2013-09-17 17:02:53', 'sub_total' => 786],
    ['id' => 76, 'placed' => '2013-09-16 17:02:53', 'sub_total' => 756],
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    ['placed' => '2013-09-19', 'sub_total' => 1566],
    ['placed' => '2013-09-18', 'sub_total' => 1542],
    ['placed' => '2013-09-17', 'sub_total' => 786],
    ['placed' => '2013-09-16', 'sub_total' => 756],
]
```

Comment: why not doing it from query if its result from database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this also: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rzv-ngp

```
$newarray = array();
foreach ($array as $value){
    $temp = explode(" ", $value['placed']);
    $date = $temp[0];
    $total = (isset($newarray[$date]['sub_total']) ? $newarray[$date]['sub_total'] + $value['sub_total']: $value['sub_total']);
    $newarray[$date] = array('placed' => $date, 'sub_total' => $total);
}

print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: This returns me: Array
(
    [2013-09-19] => Array
        (
            [placed] => 2013-09-19
            [total_price] => 1850.6

Comment: Is it possible to get output like this: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [placed] => 2013-09-19
            [total_price] => 1850.6

Comment: yes, `print_r(array_values($newarray));` so the answer is use `$newarray = array_values($newarray);`

Answer (score 3):

```
$output=array();
foreach($yourArray as $values)
{
 $d=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($values["placed"]));
 $output[$d]["sub_total"]+=$values["sub_total"];
}

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Warning: Undefined array key "2013-09-19" in /in/SO65c on line 17

Warning: Undefined array key "sub_total" in /in/SO65c on line 17

Warning: Undefined array key "2013-09-18" in /in/SO65c on line 17

Warning: Undefined array key "sub_total" in /in/SO65c on line 17

Warning: Undefined array key "2013-09-17" in /in/SO65c on line 17

Warning: Undefined array key "sub_total" in /in/SO65c on line 17

Warning: Undefined array key "2013-09-16" in /in/SO65c on line 17

Warning: Undefined array key "sub_total" in /in/SO65c on line 17
Array
(
    [2013-09-19] => Array
        (
            [sub_total] => 1566
        )

    [2013-09-18] => Array
        (
            [sub_total] => 1542
        )

    [2013-09-17] => Array
        (
            [sub_total] => 786
        )

    [2013-09-16] => Array
        (
            [sub_total] => 756
        )

)
```

**[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/SO65c)**

Comment: Error: Undefined index: 2013-09-19

Comment: That's a notice, not an error. You can define that index before if you please

Comment: Snippets should not be used where Notices, Warnings, or Errors are generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can have that kind of array at querying time. Something like

```
select date_field_name, other_field
from table_name
group by Day(date_field_name)
```

After that you can use a use `foreach()` to work with each day's data!

Comment: This SQL will be incorrect if the date set contains dates from different years or different months.

Answer (score 1):

Try using sub query

```
select field_name,
       DAY(date_field) as date,
       (
        select sum(sub_total)
        where DAY(date_field)=date
       ) as sub_total
from table_name
group by day(date_field)
```

Comment: While using SQL is a logical approach, I do not see the need for a subquery on every row selected.  This will not be an efficient query.

Answer (score 0):

Because the datetime expression is consistently formatted with its date substring first, you only need to isolate the characters that occur before the first space.  Use this substring for grouping.

Check if the date has been encountered before.  If not, create a reference variable and push that into the result array.  If/When the same date is encountered again, add the new sub-total to the cached sub_total in the related reference.  All changes to reference variables will be reflected in the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dRD0q))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $date = strtok($row['placed'], ' ');
    if (!isset($ref[$date])) {
        $ref[$date] = ['placed' => $date, 'sub_total' => $row['sub_total']];
        $result[] = &$ref[$date];
    } else {
        $ref[$date]['sub_total'] += $row['sub_total'];
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
$result = array();
foreach($shop as $value)
{
    if (!isset($result[$value['placed']]))
    {
        $result[$value['placed']] = array('placed' => $value['placed'], 'sub_total' => 0);
    }
    $result[$value['placed']]['sub_total'] += $value['sub_total'];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This unexplained answer is incorrect because it groups on datetime, not date.