# Group by date in php

Tags: php

my json looks like this

```
[
{
    "date": "2017-04-01",
    "1": "5198"
},
{
    "date": "2017-04-01",
    "4": "5149"
},
{
    "date": "2017-04-02",
    "9": "5303"
},
{
    "date": "2017-04-02",
    "14": "5216"
}....  }]
```

How could I get It grouped by days like this:

```
[
{
    "date": "2017-04-01",
    "1": "5198",
    "4": "5149"
},
{
    "date": "2017-04-02",
    "9": "5303"
    "14": "5216"
}....  }]
```

And I need it to be grouped by days because I will use output data in c3.js chart, my php code:

```
foreach ($data as $row) {
$mano[] = array(
    'date' => $row['date'],
    $row['id'] => $row['iteration']
);
}
```

Comment: Is this data coming from a database query?

Comment: yes , SELECT `campaign_id`, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP)) AS `date`, SUM(`iterationCount`) AS iteration FROM statistics , campaign WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND statistics.campaign_id=campaign.id GROUP BY `date`,id ORDER BY `date`

Comment: found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997259/group-php-array-by-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is by doing a loop then group to date key first. Then just use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to re-index

```
$mano = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $mano[$row["date"]]["date"] = $row["date"];
    $mano[$row["date"]][$row["id"]] = $row["iteration"];
}
$mano = array_values($mano);
print_r($mano);
```

Comment: I don't know where you guys see $row['id'] or $row['iteratrion'] in the JSON posted in the question. Imo id and iteration were used as meta vars to describe the real keys and values. The first half of this answer solved the question perfectly, by getting the real key. **But the last edit removed the working part**. @moderewer, could you tell us if the edited answer still works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$mano = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    if( ! key_exists($row['date'], $mano) ) {
        $mano[$row['date']] = [];
    }
    $mano[$row['date']][] = [ $row['id'] => $row['iteration'] ];
}
```

Comment: It's almost what I need but could I move date in here? {[
        {
         date: "2017-04-01",    "1": "5198",  "4": "5149"..
        },

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.